# Javascript / jQuery - Full Page Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some sort of solution/plugin to make it so that I can take full page content, and slide it in from the left or right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at supersized jquery plugin...

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

And also the Fullscreen Slit Slider...

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/